# How to convert hex to uint8_t using ruby

Tags: ruby, hex, decimal, decode, data-conversion

I have a string

```
6e6de179a94a4b406efab31f29d216c0e2ff0000
```

which I am told is defined as uint8_t and unpacks as latitude [8], longitude [8] and altitude [4].

I think this hex should decode to `54.58335` `-5.70542` `-15`.

How could I decode such a string using Ruby?

Comment: I have been advised the string is compiled using: https://gist.github.com/comms365/20d0ccff6c2827d09f6bb90f2da162f8

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fun question :)

The string is 40 hex chars long, so it represents 20 bytes.

Looking at your link, that would be 8 bytes for latitude, 8 bytes for longitude, and 4 bytes for the altitude. To be honest, I just tried the different parameters for `pack` and `unpack` until it looked like the desired floats:

```
hex = "6e6de179a94a4b406efab31f29d216c0e2ff0000"

lat_hex, lon_hex, alt_hex = hex[0,16], hex[16, 16], hex[32, 8]
lat_int, lon_int, alt_int = lat_hex.to_i(16), lon_hex.to_i(16), alt_hex.to_i(16)
p [lat_int].pack('q>').unpack('D').first
# 54.583297
p [lon_int].pack('q>').unpack('D').first
# -5.705235
```

Here's a shorter way:

```
hex.scan(/../).map{ |x| x.hex }.pack('C*').unpack('DDL')
# => [54.583297, -5.705235, 65506]
```

I'm not sure about the altitude. Since it's stored as an integer, it's probably modified later with some linear function to fit the GPS precision and the usual altitude range.